# Netflix-zuul TCP connections

Tags: netflix-zuul, netflix

Does Zuul support TCP connections? If not, is it possible to extend it?
I want to use Zuul as my load balancer. The problem is that my clients have https/http connections and some of them have tcp connections.

Comment: https/http don't have to be over tcp.

Answer (score 1):

I made a little research and I found an issue on github. This question has been asked and the answer is: It does not support.

http://techblog.netflix.com/2016/09/zuul-2-netflix-journey-to-asynchronous.html

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/1420